# SWIFT : Update an Array in one controller but use the updated array in another controller

Tags: arrays, swift, class, variables

I am quite new to IOS programming and swift and I could use some help.
What I am trying to do is the following :
I am having three Controllers A,B & C .
C is the Controller that holds an empty array of UIimages

```
class DataController {
    var imagesTaken = [UIImage]()
    }
```

I call an instance of my Controller C in my Controller A and I append the array by adding photos.
This works fine.

How I could call the updated array in Controller B ? So far when I call controller C array it just makes a new instance with 0 elements...(makes sense I guess..)

I am quite new at this , so be patient :)

Comment: Where are you calling Controller B from? Controller A or C?

Comment: You need to decide which controller owns the array of images, then the others need to read from or pass updates to this owner.

Comment: Surely you are again and again creating new object of Controller C thats why you are losing array value.

Comment: @Kudos , I know..that's what I am trying to avoid..  At ,Joakim Controller C has the image Array , but as Kudos mentioned, whenever I call it from another controller it get's a fresh copy with no values...

Comment: @IOANNIS The solution is create object of Controller C only once and pass its object whereever you need it.

Comment: @Kudos , When I call Controller C from Controller A it works and I can append the array by adding photos, when I call the Controller C from Controller B, it makes a new object/instance with no elements in the array..I want to call in Controller B the updated array...

Comment: So make a variable of type Controller C and pass object from Controller A to Controller B

Comment: How could I pass an object from A to B ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok a solution was found.
As Kudos proposed,

- I created a new object/instance "array A" of Controller C in Controller A and updated the array within Controller A.
- In controller B I created an empty array, "array B"
- Using prepare for  segue, I set the "array B" = "array A"

I attach the code as reference :

```
@IBAction func tableViewButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tableView", sender: self)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "tableView" {
                let destinationVC = segue.destination as! TableViewController
                destinationVC.dataArray = dataControllerPhoto.imagesTaken
            }
        }
```

Finally I found the below site that includes six ways to pass data from one class to another :
https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/